# To include or not include missing values in statistical analysis?

Tags: statistics

I have some data I'm calculating frequencies, means, and medians on. Of course, some of the data is missing.

I have not been including the missing values, but I've noticed that my results for my calculations for frequencies and chi-squared tests are sometimes vastly different than that of my boss'. He kept the missing values in and I did not. My boss' isn't a statistician, by the way.

So I guess my question is, should I keep missing values or not? And why would I want to or not want to keep them in my calculations.

Here is a sample of what I'm doing:

Evaluate proportion of patients with or without insurance
Evaluate proportion of patients grouped by Insurance Status and whether or not they tested ER positive
Evaluate proportion of patients grouped by Insurance Status and subdivided by Race

EXAMPLE:

```
         Insurance Status   Yes     No
ERstatus

yes                          50     112

no                           23     87
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't "missing" mean a value isn't there to include?! Do you mean, for example, that you are coding insurance status as no = 0, yes = 1, and if you don't know insurance status, you are leaving it as 0, because that is the default value of an integer variable? That is most certainly wrong. On the other hand, if the people for whom data is missing are correlated with what you are trying to measure, dropping those people from the analysis can also bias the result. You will need to be much more clear about your data and procedures to get a good answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course. You should eliminate mistakes (miscounts and etc errors) from result computing. There are [some rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) for its processing. But there is no sense to include 'mistakes' in result...